# Disabling several elements on one button

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to toggle disabled status of several element using one button. I did function which only toggle status of one element.

```
    Disabled() {
      var element = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("input");
      if (element.disabled == true) {
          element.disabled = false;
      } else {
          element.disabled = true;
      }
    }
```

what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the input's disabled property to a variable in your code and change that variable on click:

```
<input ng-disabled="disabled"/>
<button ng-click="disabled = !disabled">
  Disable
</button>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-n78yrt?file=home%2Fhome.html

Update: Stackblitz changed to work without ng-syntax

Comment: It doesnt want to work. Is it some way to change my code to work in the way i want ? Becuase ng - bidings sometime dont work in my project and dunno why and it is one of these moments.

Comment: I updated my stackblitz example to work without it. But i would recommend to take a look why ng-binding doesn't work sometimes. Because to only work a round this, will definitly will bring you to a limit.